# change method resolution order

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

is it possible to change the method resolution order?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a=a
    def method(self):
        print('A method')
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, b1, b2):
        self.b1=b1
        self.b2=b2
    def method(self):
        print('B method')
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        if name=='A':
            A.__init__(self, a=kwargs['a'])
        elif name=='B':
            B.__init__(self, b1=kwargs['b1'], b2=kwargs['b2'])
```

I want change the MRO if the input `name` is 'B', so that when i call:

```
>>>c=C(name='B', b1=2, b2=3)
>>>c.method()
```

it returns 'B method'.

Thanks

Comment: While you *could* change the MRO with a weird metaclass, it seems like replacing C with a factory function or using composition instead of multiple inheritance would be a better solution.

Comment: a) Why? b) Store `name` and override `method()` in C and call `B.method(self)` conditionally, similar to what you already have in  `C.__init__()`. c) You constructor jumps over `B`'s initialization. This will bite you.

Comment: dhke, your solution is the simplest. Thanks both... sorry but what do you intend for composition?

Comment: Have C instances contain either an A or a B depending on the `name` argument and delegate to the contained object for `method`.

Answer (score -1):

Just change the definition of the C class to :
class C(B, A):
    ...
ie : change the order of the inherited classes.